# Jquery code if checkbox is checked, select all other checkboxes - Working with Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, checkbox

I have a little problem and I still couldn't find a solution. It's about a table in my view and every table row have his own checkbox. There is another main checkbox that should check all other checkboxes, if I'm selecting it.

My problem is that it doesn't work like I want it.

View :

```
// thats the main checkbox, that should select all other checkboxes 

<th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all"/>All</th>
 // and some other non important <th> fields 


 all table rows 

                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            // every line checkbox
                            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{$product->id}}">
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $product->name  }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $product->tld  }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach($product->tags as $tag)
                                {{$tag->name}},
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $product->created_at->format('d.m.y')  }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select-all').on('click', function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                $('.select-all').each(function() {
                    this.checked = true;
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.select-all').each(function() {
                    this.checked = false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Jquery script is okay, If I add the "select-all" class to my `<input>` tag INSIDE of my foreach loop and also at the  field outsite of the loop, all checkboxes getting selected. If I remove the class from the  field inside of my foreach loop, it doesn't work anymore. My problem now is that I only want to select all boxes with my main checkbox.. currently, it doesn't matter which checkbox I select, every checkbox will be selected. ( so I don't have the option to select a single row or two.

the select-all class is just in my main checkbox input field, not in my input field inside of my foreach loop.

thanks for taking your time and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your jQuery selector for picking out the sub check boxes is slightly off. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select-all').on('click', function() {
            var checkAll = this.checked;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                this.checked = checkAll;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this works just perfect!! thank you alot, I'm still learning jquery :)

Comment: You're welcome :)! 

Although it's worth noting, the "input[type=checkbox]" selector will select all checkboxes on the page (including the select all option). Therefore if you add any more later (even out with the table), they'll be selected/deselected too. Adding a separate class like @Anoop suggested would prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a different class for the sub checkboxes.
Then you can do,

```
$(".select-all").change(function() {
  $(".subCheckbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

You don't need to loop through all the checkboxes to check them.

Just use the class selector and `prop()` method.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5373/)

Comment: I see it works but haven't worked for me :/ but thanks anyway, the answer below yours helped me alot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select-all").change(function() {
   $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',this.checked);})
```